# How to organize angular workspace to share some components between subprojects?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have Angular CLI workspace that contains 4 UI application and 1 library which is API consumer.

Now there is a need to share some components between UI applications. I don't want to create separate library project because every change in shared component will require developer to rebuild the library in order to see the changes in the UI.

Are there any good practices on that topic?

Options that I think of are:

1. As the last resort - create library project and build it everytime
2. Dont care about separation, just import components between projects eg in project A do import `../../projects/B/app/src/ComponentFromB`
3. Create library project, but never build it but rather split components in that project into separate modules - like Angular Material components - and import modules directly

3 is kind of mix of 1 and 2 with addition on creating module per component/utility. Maybe module/component is not needed and I could directly import components and redelare them in "local" shared modules whenever it is needed?

Any other alternatives?

Comment: To DV - yes, it is opinion based, and this is exactly how it supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to this.

First of all, it's usually required to create a library or separate project due to versioning.
If you intend to use this components in two different projects there will be times where you wouldn't want to use latest component version on both sides. For example - new version of component works on one project, but breaks layout on the other one. Or it's just broken, incompatible, etc.

To work with multiple projects there are numerous tools already, one of the most popular is **lerna** https://github.com/lerna/lerna though it can be an overkill for your task.

If you're worried about building new version very time - other solution would be to build this library and serve **prebuilt version** via internal CDN. For example gitlab provides NPM registry out of the box, so CI/CD could be building a new version and publishing there. This way you can use prebuilt version of the library and not rebuild it every time.

The easy way here is to use a **git submodule** and include in two different project repos. This is very easy to do, but be wary that submodules aren't very nice to work with in a longer term.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have some remarks. 1) First asumption is wrong - whole workspace will be in the exact same revision. 2) changes made to shared components must simply NOT break any of the application - therfore robust set of e2e and unit tests. 3) CDN is even worst then building it locally after any change to see the effects in each application. 4) "shared component library" will always be bundled into the each application. I might take look inti lerna but I think it covers diffrent step of app development - not development itself but post processing - publishing and merging.

Comment: Nrwl would be better choice here I think. I was considering nrwl workspaces at the begining but then I have found out that angular-cli is actually support multiproject workspaces and it would be enough in our case.

Comment: Also I think you have assumed that shared component will be not subject to frequent changes - therfore propositiof on prebuild bin in CDN - but this is not the case. At this point, those can change as frequent as any other part of the workspace.